# Mysql query - summ total by country, region and take percentage of total (general)

Tags: mysql, group-by, percentage

I have two tables
1. Geo
2. Sales

1. Geo with fields
   Country, city, userId
2. Sales with fields
   UserId, sales_amount

I need to make query and have result with fileds
country / city / sales_amount (by city) / percentage of total(general) by city

How can I make it without join sales table on itself?
Can you help my with query?

I have only idea with join sales to itself (but it doesn't work)

I've tried to make join Sales to itself but it doesn't work

```
Select Geo.country, Geo.city, sum(Sales_amount), 
(sum(Sales_amount))/"t" as "percentage of general total"
From Geo
Join 
Sales
On Geo.UserId = Sales.UserId
Join
(Select userId, summ(sales_amount) as "total" from Sales) as "t" 
ON t.userId = Geo.UserId
Group by Geo.country, Geo.city
```

and nothing in result(

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A join between the tables and then summing by city.
The percentage can be retrieved by a division of each sum with the total:

```
select 
  g.country, 
  g.city,
  sum(s.sales_amount) citysales,
  100.0 * sum(s.sales_amount) / (select sum(sales_amount) from sales) percentage
from geo g left join sales s
on g.userid = s.userid
group by g.country, g.city
```

Comment: maybe you know some optimizations of query or another way to solve it? 
cause sales table is so big and when I run query it takes a lot of time

Comment: Indexes for the joined columns: geo.userid and sales.userid would help (if they're not already there). Also if your version of Mysql is 8.0, you could use a CTE in place of `(select sum(sales_amount) from sales)`, although I believe it's already optimized, so it is evaluated only once.